# VMWare Virtual Machines: can be accessed from Internet?

Tags: virtualization

I'm new with VMWare Player virtual machines. I created two: one with Windows 7 and other one with Ubuntu Desktop.

The host machine has connection to Internet, a firewall, etc. I can access it from anywhere using its IP X.X.X.X, but **I don't want that those VMs be public**. I need them in the host machine, but that only can be accessed if I login in the host machine first.

I'm worried that their services (node.js, apache, telnet, etc.) could be accessed from internet too, in some way.

Can VMWare Player make public these VMs?  How can I make these VMs privates again?

Answer (score 4):

In short, no, at least not on default settings. By default, VMware provides virtual machines with Internet access through NAT. Basically, this means that VMware turns your computer into a virtual router, one that firewalls inbound connections, and puts the virtual machines behind that virtual router. They are essentially invisible even to computers inside your home network; all outbound VM traffic will appear to originate from the host machine and the host machine will not allow any inbound connections to the VMs.

To make your VMs Internet accessible, you would have to go into the VM's adapter settings and change the adapter mode to "bridged" - If you do this, the virtual machines will act like real machines directly connected to your home router. But assuming your home router has a firewall and performs NAT (which the vast majority of consumer routers do), you would then have to go into your router settings and forward some incoming ports to the VMs to finally make them public.